# Set value only upon jQueryUI autocomplete select event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete which will set the value of `#resource_id` upon the `select` event.  If a `select` event occurs, but then the user continues to edit `#resourceFile`, I wish to remove `#resource_id` from being posted (or set to zero or NULL so the server knows).

The following script doesn't work since the `change` event occurs after the `select` event even if `#resourceFile` isn't later changed.

How can this be accomplished?

```
$(".addResource").click(function() {$("#dialog-addResource").dialog("open");});
$("#dialog-addResource").dialog({
    autoOpen: false, resizable:false, height: 200, width: 600, modal: true,
    open: function() {
        $('#resourceFile').val('');
        $('#resource_id').val('');
    },
    buttons: [
        {
            text: 'Save',
            click: function() {
                var data=$(this).find($('#resource_id').val()?':input':':input:not(#resource_id)').serializeArray();
                console.log(this,data)
                $.post('/pages_back/display/addResource',data,function (rsp){
                    console.log(rsp);
                    },'json');
            }
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            click    : function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
        }
    ]
});

$("#resourceFile").autocomplete({
    source: "/pages_back/display/getResources",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('set');
        $('#resource_id').val(ui.item.id);
    },
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('changed');
        $('#resource_id').val('');  //Is it better to set to null or use removeAttr('value')?
    }
});
```

.

```
<div id="dialog-addResource" title="Add Resource" style="display:none">
    <span>Add Resource: </span>
    <input type="text" id="resourceFile" name="file" />
    <input type="hidden" id="resource_id" name="resource_id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page_id" value="{{ id }}" />
</div>
```

Comment: By "continues to edit resourcefile" do you mean continues to add or remove characters from the autocomplete box, or something else?

Comment: @BobRodes  Exactly as you said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a very elegant solution, but the following will work:

```
$("#resourceFile").autocomplete({
    source: "/pages_back/display/getResources",
    minLength: 2,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('set',ui);
        $('#resources_id').val(ui.item.id).data('name',ui.item.value);
    },
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        console.log('changed');
        if($('#resources_id').data('name')!=$('#resourceFile').val()) {
            $('#resources_id').val('');  //Is it better to set to null or use removeAttr('value')?
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That `data` feature comes in handy in a pretty wide range of edge-case scenarios.  :)

Comment: @BobRodes  Yes it does!  I was thinking of using a global variable, but that is even less elegant.  Thanks

Comment: Yes, true.  I found `data` especially useful when working with displaying child tables in dialog boxes, to pass the parent id into the child table context.